# Does AChartEngine DoughnutChartView support labels?

Tags: android, achartengine

I am trying to get the DoughnutChartView to display labels inside of the chart.  Essentially, if I have chart created with three values, say 25, 30, and 45, I would like to see this labels displayed within my DoughnutChartView.

From the demo code, I've reviewed the BudgetPieChart.java.  It shows the embedded labels in the chart.  I've tried to mimic the settings for DoughnutChartView but no luck.  Within the DoughnutChartView, I am able to toggle the labels by using .setShowLabels().  So, I can see that working!  However, it seems like the .setDisplayValues() method does not work for DoughnutChartViews.

Does the DoughnutChartView support embedding labels?

Thanks.

Steve

Comment: That's currently implemented for pie chart only.

Comment: @Dan, thanks for the sanity check.  I added a feature request for this option.

Answer (score 0):

Set showLabels true.

```
DefaultRenderer renderer = buildCategoryRenderer(colors);
    renderer.setShowLabels(true);
    renderer.setInScroll(true);
    renderer.setStartAngle(90);
```